# StrictMode confusion - how is this the wrong thread?

Tags: android, file-io, handler, looper, android-strictmode

My issue:

> 12-18 17:05:03.336: DEBUG/StrictMode(2112): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=2073 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2

From the factory method

> 12-18 17:05:03.336: DEBUG/StrictMode(2112):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)

Then in my code

> 12-18 17:05:03.336:
>   DEBUG/StrictMode(2112):  at
>   blah.ImageCache.getFromCache(ImageCache.java:248)
>
> 12-18 17:05:03.336:
>   DEBUG/StrictMode(2112):
>     at
>   blah2$LoaderThread$1.handleMessage(blah.java:63)

Important snip-its

> class LoaderThread extends HandlerThread {
>
> public Handler mHandler;
>
> public LoaderThread(String name) {
>     super(name);
>    }
>
> @Override
>    public void onLooperPrepared(){
>     mHandler = new Handler(){
>      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
>       Bitmap bit =ImageCache.getInstance().getFromCache((String)msg.obj,ImageCache.USE_DISK);
>      }
>     };
>    }
>   }

The getFromCache method in the ImageCache class calls

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fLoc);
```

Which seems to be running on the UI thread, but it makes no sense to me. Shouldn't this be getting called on a background thread? This was the goal of using [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) after all...

The LoadThread class is created in my onCreate(bundle) like this

> LoaderThread loader = new LoaderThread("imgLoader")
>
> loader.start();

and messages are passed from the UI thread via the handler

> loader.mHandler.dispatchMessage(loader.mHandler.obtainMessage(args..));

I'm wondering if this has to do with the getInstance method which is static

> public static synchronized ImageCache getInstance() {
>
> if (_instance==null) { 
>     _instance = new ImageCache(); 
>    } 
>    return _instance; 
>   }

Comment: @smith234: Why are you using `HandlerThread` instead of just an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I wanted to see how it performs with loading images in a `ListView`.  With an `AsyncTask` I would have to spawn a new one for each drawable. With the `HandlerThread` I can just post messages to its looper (which loads the file from disk and posts a message back to the UI's looper which can update the row in question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like an ass now, but I was calling the wrong method on my handler...

the wrong way

```
loader.mHandler.dispatchMessage(loader.mHandler.obtainMessage(args..));
```

the right way

```
loader.mHandler.sendMessage(loader.mHandler.obtainMessage(args..));
```

So somehow the messages were being run through the handler still, just on the UI thread instead of the background one.

Comment: Which means that `StrictMode` was able to fulfill its intended goal by signaling a potential problem in your program that you were able to fix. :)

Comment: @Jean Hominal thats right! I've been enjoying using `StrictMode` to find these issues, this one just threw me a curve ball though.